# bootstrap responsive card show hide more content

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

i'm looking for a solution without JS.

what i want to get is a simple gridding of cards / tiles which have a image with text and a button with read more. this button should show the more content with a overlapping.

what i have is from the v4 doc https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card:

```
<div class="card">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-block">
    <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">show more</a>
    <div class="toggle">more text text text text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But how i can solve this issue with the more content to overlapp other cards and not to put all of them donw which are on the same line?

Comment: I guess you still need javascript as i see no documentation available that offers such functionality.

Comment: I mean, the content that expands should over other cards. this should works without JS, as far as i know with z-index or something like else. but how to... :(

Comment: Yeah you could add `position:relative;` and `z-index:9999 (higher than other elements)` to active card so selected card is on top. But i think you still need a `active class` card. I would suggest to make a simply javascript / jquery function for this. I think it's not possible with only the css.